# SSRS How to Modify Axis to display chart properly?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

[image: My graph]

Is there any way to change interval between 1 and 5 to 1. Then, after that uses 10 as an interval? I tried scale break, but it doesn't work. My max data is 80. We can't really see the chart here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't specify a changing custom interval so the axis values vary as you mentioned.

The Interval can be set in the **Axis Properties**. Right-click on the axis and click on **Properties**. The Interval defaults to **Auto**. You can change it to any value or an expression but it would use that value for the entire axis.

There are also options to use scale breaks or use a logarithmic scale. If you use logarithmic scale, the intervals would go from 1 to 10 to 100 since your max data is 80 - still not what you need though.

Here's some more info:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239317(v=sql.105).aspx